# Rocket core implements the RV64G version of RISCV?

Tags: riscv

I wanted to know , which version of the riscv ISA is the released rocket core capable of implementing.

Since it supports Double precision floating point , am i safe to assume that it is the RV64G version .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Rocket core implements RV64G.*

If you'd like to manually verify this yourself, you can check the [ctrl code](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket/blob/master/src/main/scala/ctrl.scala)'s decode tables.

However, you can turn off the FPU in the [parameter settings](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/PublicConfigs.scala) of the rocket-chip generator, by setting `case BuildFPU =>...` to `None` (or by invoking the `SmallConfig` when building Rocket from the command line).

Fun fact, in inspecting the decode tables, you can also see additional custom extension instructions used to implement the "RoCC" interface, which communicates with any attached accelerator/co-processor cores ("ROcket Coprocessor Coordination"). By default they are off, as `buildROCC` is set to `None`.

***Edit:** As you point out, Rocket (currently) eschews implementing the fdiv and fsqrt instructions. These will trap and will be executed in software (assuming you are running Rocket on top of a kernel that implements these instructions). In fact, the current riscv-gcc port will not emit these instructions by default, but will instead emit soft-float versions on fdiv and fsqrt.

**References**

- [ctrl code](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket/blob/master/src/main/scala/ctrl.scala)
- [parameter/configuration file](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/PublicConfigs.scala)
- [core code](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket)
- [chip code](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip)

Comment: Ok . I went through it . Looks like the the Double precision Divide and sqrt operation haven't been incorporated in rocker core.

Comment: @SrihariSankar Good eye! I forgot that, at the moment, Rocket does not have a hardware implementation in Chisel of the divide and sqrt operation. Also, if you compile such a program, you need -fdiv to generate the divide instructions using riscv-gcc. We have Verilog implementations, just that nobody has yet ported them to Chisel.